# Deployment error with SSIS 2012 while deploying project to catalogue DB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I encountered a rather strange error earlier while deploying an SSIS project to our SSIS Catalogue DB:

> "The project or operation records do not exist or you have not been
>   granted the appropriate permissions to view them."

Now, I'm an administrator on the server and have never had any trouble deploying to it before.  I tried again just afterwards, and it worked fine.  I checked to make sure that there were no other packages running at the same time.

I did find [this recent post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/af06ccd2-e246-41ca-a6d0-f6367e78b7a6), which has the same error but no explanation as of yet.

Anybody know what the cause of this error could be?

Comment: Is it possible that you lost your connection to the server momentarily?

Comment: I suppose it is possible, but there have not been any other interruptions during this time (i.e. browsing the catalogue via SSMS is not affected), and there's no trace of any connectivity issues in any logs.

Comment: I think the last comment in this [blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/af06ccd2-e246-41ca-a6d0-f6367e78b7a6/) will be useful.

Comment: Next time check SSIS and SQL logs. It may be that your aumtification failed due to time out of password verification server. If this is not a recurring problem it will be quite difficult to trace.

Answer (score 1):

try open solution "Run as Administrator" it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your project did not exist at the time of the deployment but was created so the next time you deployed you did not get the error because it actually passed that validation.  Double Check the deployment information, the name and path of the deployment destination and confirm that those existed.